# Why does not Animation Nodes provide the uv information properly?

Tags: python, texturing, uv, node-editor, animation-nodes

Please see the sample nodes below. You can see that the object clearly has UVs and listed in the uv list however Animation Nodes is telling me that it has no uvs.

Is this a bug? Is there a way to get uvs properly in AN so I can paste it to some instances?

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Load UVs` option is hidden by default. You have to enable it.

[image]